# Add fields and remove fields with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/975VQ/3/

I want to be able to start with an input box, complete with select field and delete button, and be able to dynamically remove them and add more.

This is the JavaScript jQuery I have found and tried to modify:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var MaxInputs       = 8; //maximum input boxes allowed
var InputsWrapper   = $("#InputsWrapper"); //Input boxes wrapper ID
var AddButton       = $("#addfield"); //Add button ID

var x = InputsWrapper.length; //initlal text box count
var FieldCount=1; //to keep track of text box added

$(AddButton).click(function (e)  //on add input button click
{
        if(x <= MaxInputs) //max input box allowed
        {
            FieldCount++; //text box added increment
            //add input box
            $(InputsWrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="field_'+ FieldCount +'" value="Text '+ FieldCount +'"/><button class="removeclass">Delete</button></div>');
            x++; //text box increment
        }
return false;
});

$("body").on("click",".removeclass", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        if( x > 1 ) {
                $(this).parent('div').remove(); //remove text box
                x--; //decrement textbox
        }
return false;
}) 

});
```

It doesn't seem to work for adding or deleting input boxes and additionally doesn't seem to give any errors to say why.

Comment: Since `var AddButton = $("#addfield");` you have, you don't need to use $(AddButton) .... just AddButton will work....

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/975VQ/12/

Comment: Yup, exactly like that

Comment: @Jimmy Then your code was completly fine, you just have to fix your html take a look at the answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed to add `id` in your `html elements` and `jquery` in your page try this,

**HTML**

```
<h1>Questions</h1>
<p>Add additional questions. You can select how long you would like the reply to be.</p>
<div class="add-row">
    <input value="Why do you want this" />
    <select>
        <option value="single">Single line reply</option>
        <option value="multi">Paragraph reply</option>
    </select>
    <button class="remove">Delete</button>
</div>
<br />
<button id="addfield">Add question</button>
<br />
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#addfield').on('click', function(){
        $clone=$('.add-row:first').clone();
        $clone.insertAfter($('.add-row:last'));
    });
    $(document).on("click",".remove", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        if( $('.add-row').length > 1 ) {
                $(this).closest('div.add-row').remove(); //remove entire row
        }
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/wc8Jv/)

Updated [Demo with maxinputs](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/wc8Jv/1/)

Answer (score 2):

The reason this doesn't work is because of your two variables `InputsWrapper` and `AddButton`. Both these variables are null because there isn't any HTML that has `InputsWrapper` or `AddField` as an ID attribute

Here is the corrected HTML:

```
<h1>Questions</h1>
<p>Add additional questions. You can select how long you would like the reply to be.   </p>
<div id="InputsWrapper">
    <input value="Why do you want this">
    <select>
        <option value="single">Single line reply</option>
        <option value="multi">Paragraph reply</option>
    </select>
    <button>Delete</button>
</div>
<button id="addfield">Add question</button>
```

***[SEE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/975VQ/11/)***